# Why does systemsetup sometimes fail to do anything?

Tags: macos

I recently came across this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/pull/48583#issue-201371696

```
Mac-6:testing root# systemsetup -setlocalsubnetname blah4
setlocalsubnetname: blah4
Mac-6:testing root# systemsetup -getlocalsubnetname
Local Subnet Name: blah3
```

It's not just the `-setlocalsubnetname` - other commands also fail.

It would appear that `systemsetup` will fail intermittently. Is there a way to figure out why in the world that's the case? I've spent quite a bit of time on Google to no avail.

---

To add some details:

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/systemsetup -getlocalsubnetname
Local Subnet Name: Mithos-9
$ sudo /usr/sbin/systemsetup -setlocalsubnetname Mithos
setlocalsubnetname: Mithos
$ sudo /usr/sbin/systemsetup -getlocalsubnetname
Local Subnet Name: Mithos-9
$ sudo /usr/sbin/systemsetup -setlocalsubnetname MithosX
setlocalsubnetname: MithosX
$ sudo /usr/sbin/systemsetup -getlocalsubnetname
Local Subnet Name: MithosX
$ sudo /usr/sbin/systemsetup -setlocalsubnetname Mithos
setlocalsubnetname: Mithos
$ sudo /usr/sbin/systemsetup -getlocalsubnetname
Local Subnet Name: Mithos
```

Didn't find anything useful in the logs.

Comment: I don't have any idea what this question is about.  Can you add the relevant info to the question instead of (or in addition to) linking out to github?

Comment: My bad. I've added what relevant information that there is - though in general there's not a lot of information that I can find on `systemsetup` in general, aside from a manpage, and a couple of articles.